# Touchpad bugs: 2 fingers scroll stops working, sensitivity increases, cursor moving on its own after a move

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

On Ubuntu 20.04, my Touchpad is having weird bugs that start at random moments that I couldn't link to any special activity. It seems to just start randomly.

Here are the different effects that I can have:

- when I move the mouse, after I stop moving my finger, the cursor starts slowly moving a few pixels more which makes it very hard to be precise to click on buttons or links
- The scroll with 2 fingers stops working (I checked and the option is still enabled in Ubuntu's parameters)
- The mouse starts moving incredibly fast

Those effects stops after a while for no apparent reason.

Also, despite having separated sliders for TouchPad speed and Mouse speed, only the Mouse speed is taken into account.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update the kernel, get all the latest modules exist at the moment. If there is no module for your device, it will try to be generated. Reserve device and vendor keys for aliases in the blacklist from the output of the `dmesg` command.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea about what I could do. I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, try it, and if you delete the value of the last digit and make the reboot device. In the output of `dmesg`, you will see the error ~ `usb 1-6` and understand that it method works.

Comment: I just need to wait for the issue to happen again... Seems that asking a question about it solves it xD

Comment: I also stopped getting errors related to the touchpad recently, even after I removed this code from the blacklist. But I know at what point it happens on my device when I open ubuntu-software. I just don't use the store and I don't get any errors yet. It is quite possible that the developers have already fixed everything, but I don't want to check )